# RequireJs: Wrong module order

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, routes, requirejs, amd

I got following router.js:

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'views/settings/index'], function($, _, Backbone, SettingsView) {

    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

        container: $('div.main'),

        routes: {
                "settings": "settings"
                , "settings/:query": "settings"
        },

        settings: function(query) {
            this.container.html(SettingsView.render().el);
        }

    });

    if (Router._instance) return Router._instance;

    Router._instance = new Router();

    return Router._instance;

});
```

The router gets called in the main.js filed which is marked as first dependency in the requirejs config:

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'router'], function($, _, Backbone, router) {

    // ajax settings (sent cors cookies)
    $.ajaxSetup({ xhrFields: { withCredentials: true } });

    // register master router
    window.router = router;

    // start backbone history
    Backbone.history.start({ root: "/" });          

});
```

In some view I now want to do:

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'router'], function($, _, Backbone, router) {

    var View = Backbone.View.extend({

        initialize: function() {
            router.on('route:settings', this.change, this);
        },

        change: function(query) {
            // load some new content for example
        }

    });

    return View;

});
```

Than I am getting this error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined
```

**UPDATE:**
I added a console.log to each module. So I know in which order the modules are executed. I mentioned that requirejs has the wrong order:

```
view.js -> main.js -> router.js
```

instead of:

```
router.js -> main.js -> view.js
```

Let see how I can solve this

**UPDATE2:**
I now wrapped the router event binding part into a setTimeout loop:

```
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.router.on('route:settings', this.select, this);        
        }.bind(this), 20);
```

And see there it works!

This truly just is a fix but nevertheless a fix :)

Comment: Honestly I think you shouldn't fix your problem with a setTimeout in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to create a singleton instance on your router?

Requirejs resolves every module only once as far as I understand and
as far as I would expect from any decent module loader.

```
#router.js
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'views/settings/index'], 
  function($, _, Backbone, SettingsView) {
  //your code omitted ...

  //no need to do this
  //if (Router._instance) return Router._instance;
  //Router._instance = new Router();
  //return Router._instance;

  //this should work as well and give you a "singleton" instance
  return new Router();
```

});

Comment: You need so far an singelton so that you always get the same instance of an object. The magic is the new keyword ^^

Comment: Maybe I was not clear enough.
Every loaded module will be executed only once and the results (the object(s) you return) will be cached and reused.

Answer (score 1):

1. please check if the names/path you have given to requirejs.config() is correct. I have hit the wall hard a few times because I had a slight typo. requirejs doesnt return any errors on such cases but sadly only undefined.
2. If you are dead sure that there is no typo I'd try to include main.js as an explicit dependency on the definition of your view.

Comment: to one: it can't be a typo. The router.js file is directly in the root dir so there is no path shortcut. To two: This is a really good idea! I tried it and unfortunately it didn't work. However I slowly assume we got a bug

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to return a reference to the `Router` object at the end of the first `define`.

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'views/settings/index'], function($, _, Backbone, SettingsView) {

    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

        container: $('div.main'),

        routes: {
            "settings": "settings"
            , "settings/:query": "settings"
        },

        settings: function(query) {
            this.container.html(SettingsView.render().el);
        }

    });

    var Singletonizer = function(Singleton) {
        if (Singleton._instance) return Singleton._instance;

        Singleton._instance = new Singleton();

        Singletonizer(Singleton);
    };

    return Singletonizer(Router);
});
```

Comment: I now added an event listener directly in the file where the router gets called. There event listening succeeds. In the view itself I get the error. So for some reason the router isn't available as module ....